# Get Group Names for Massive HDF5 File

Tags: python, c++, hdf5, h5py

I have HDF5 files which can be in excess of 50 Gb in size. I'm only interested in grabbing the names of all groups within one of the top-level groups. E.g.,

```
f = h5py.File('my_file.hdf')
names = f['top_level_group'].keys()
```

There are over 1,000,000 groups, and running the above code takes hours to complete. Is there some way to do this in a reasonable amount of time? I feel like it shouldn't take more than a few seconds to simply get the names of all groups.

**EDIT**

My actual production code is in C++ and uses the C++ hdf5 API, which includes the function `GetObjnameByIdx()`. This allows me to time how long it takes to read each individual group name and output to a log file. I left this running over the weekend and the code has still not completed. My timing results so far are given below:

[image]

At first, the code started at about 1-1.5 ms per group. This seems slow to me, as it implies about 30-35 minutes to read all the groups. Regardless, not long after, it's at 2 ms (at this point, I went home for the weekend, figuring I would have a complete graph by Monday).

Lo', I was mistaken. Noting that this is a semi-log plot, the logarithmic shape actually represents a linear trend. Interestingly, at some point, it suddenly jumped from 10 ms per read to 2.5 seconds per read (with jumps up to 25 seconds!). The sum of read times in the log add up to 64.5 hours.

I'm unable to reproduce this issue in other files I generate (we have at least 3 production files that have this issue, however). I generated files that are the same size and structure as the production files which have issues, and I generated them using the same functions from the production code,. Those test files took 1-2 seconds to load.

I know that the files are not fully corrupt, because we *do get results*, as long as we let it run to completion. The data is there, it's just taking forever to access.

At this point, since I can't reproduce the issue in a test file, my question is probably null and void for StackOverflow, but I'm at a complete loss as to what I should do.

Comment: How long does it take to list all groups with `h5ls -r myfile.hdf`? This gives an idea of of the lower limit of what is possible.

Comment: Extrapolating out from the current print rate, it'll most likely take an hour or two. However, just accessing the group names themselves ought to be orders of magnitude faster than printing them out.

Comment: Try to redirect to /dev/null. (`h5ls -r myfile.hdf > /dev/null`) to rule out any effect of printing and scrolling.

Comment: 41 minutes for /dev/null redirect

Answer (score 2):

That's odd. It shouldn't take hours to get the group names/keys. 
Are you doing something besides accessing the groups?

Here is a very simple example that creates 1,000,000 groups, closes the HDF5 file and reopens to get the keys. It runs in a minute or so on my Windows laptop (24GB RAM).

```
with h5py.File('SO_59668177.h5','w') as h5f:
    for g_cnt in range(1000000):
        h5f.create_group('grp_' +str(g_cnt))

with h5py.File('SO_59668177.h5','r') as h5f:
    names = h5f.keys()
    print (len(names))
```

Based OP's comments about datasets, I modified the code above to add a dataset to each group (plus some timing output). I then ran for different #s of groups (increasing h5 file size). Timing data summarized below. Note that time to access the groups/keys is almost unchanged for 1,000,000 groups in a 50GB file (vs 10,000 groups in a 0.5GB file). However, there are other performance bottle necks (as seen in the name length count).

**10,000 groups (0.5GB)**
time to create groups and data = 4.13
time to access groups = 0.000831
time to count groups= 0.0227

**100,000 groups (5GB)**
time to create groups and data = 44.88
time to access groups = 0.000678
time to count groups = 0.266

**1,000,000 groups (50GB)**
time to create groups and data = 983.8
time to access groups = 0.00109
time to count groups = 724.9

Modified code below.

```
size = 1000000
dim=80
arr=np.random.rand(dim*dim,1).reshape(dim,dim)

start = time.clock()
with h5py.File('SO_59668177.h5','w') as h5f:
    for g_cnt in range(size):
        grp=h5f.create_group('grp_' +str(g_cnt))
        grp.create_dataset('dset_1',data=arr)
print ('create groups and data')
print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )

start = time.clock() 
with h5py.File('SO_59668177.h5','r') as h5f:
    names = h5f.keys()
    print ('access groups')
    print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )

    start = time.clock() 
    print (len(names))
    print ('count groups')
    print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )
```

Comment: A minute still seems pretty absurd, doesn't it? Regardless, my guess as to why yours only takes about a minute is because there's not also 50 Gb of data in the file.

Comment: If you remove the print statement, it actually loads in just a second or two

Comment: Depends on your comparison. :) I tried to open my example file with HDF Viewer (written in Java), and it's still trying to display (6 minutes later).

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the read time is dependent on the size of each group. My production code is in C++, which allows me to read individual groups at a time. I saw that different subsets (all of the same number of groups) took vastly different amounts of time to load depending on how large the groups were.

Comment: "remove the print statement" -- not surprised. So the time in my example is spent counting the keys, not getting them. Next (rhetorical) question is: does it take longer b/c you have a 50GB file? How many datasets do you have in each  group?

Comment: The hdf file contains information for many surface meshes. Each group represents a single mesh and contains 2 datasets, one for vertices and one for facet indexing. For large meshes, these datasets can get quite large. The 50 Gb of information is stored nearly entirely within these groups (some additional groups exist, but they are essentially empty in comparison)

Comment: I updated my example to add a dataset to each group, along with some timing output. I then ran for different #s of groups (size of h5 file). I modified my answer to reflect the findings.